# "code ." not opening vscode on centos 7 on virtualbox

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I installed vscode through various means. It's under my /etc/yum.repos.d. Whenever I run it, though, nothing opens.

I tried
`code --verbose`
and I got

```
[24395:0905/184637.258019:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(247)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[24395:0905/184637.258063:ERROR:env.cc(226)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

I'm not sure what to do anymore. I keep looking stuff up but nothing seems to work.

I have Centos 7 Minimal iso if that's relevant.

Comment: The error message says "Missing X server or $DISPLAY". Are you running an X server? Is the DISPLAY environment variable set correctly?

Comment: This really isn't a programming problem. It's a generic probably about running GUI applications on Linux. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Quentin Questions about [software tools commonly used by programmers](/help/on-topic) are on topic here. This question is on topic on both sites.

Comment: @JohnKugelman — Yes, but as I said, this problem is generic to running GUI applications on Linux. There's nothing specific about VS Code here.

Comment: That's fine information for an answer. The asker doesn't know what the root cause is.

Comment: BTW, "Centos minimal ISO" sounds very much like it would *not* include an X server.

Comment: @JosephPark Are you running in graphical mode with a desktop or text mode with just a plain black terminal? VS Code is a graphical IDE and will only work if you are in a desktop like GNOME or KDE. As paxdiablo says, CentOS Minimal does not have a desktop environment by default. You'll either need to install one, switch to a different Linux distro that already has one, or use a text-based editor such as Vim or Emacs.

Comment: Just a comment on the side: a google search for **ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(247)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY** (the error message without the timestamps) gives many results, the top 3 for me make it quite clear where the problem lies ... just saying. I bet that the search and a cursory glance over the results was actually way faster than typing the question here...

Comment: FWIW, I run vscode on my Windows host and connect it to vscode server in my Linux VM (and MobaXTerm to get a shell if the vscode shell is inadequate). That's just because having to handle things like Alt-Tab program switching across host/VM is a pain. So I just start the VM then relegate it to doing nothing other than serving ssh and vscode. Just putting that forward as another possibility, one that doesn't require X server in Centos.

Comment: And re "I installed vscode through various means", that sounds like a very iffy situation :-)